# pip install virtualenv where are the scripts

Tags: python, virtualenv, pip, setup.py

This is probably an incredibly stupid question, but I'm testing out a python package that I wrote that has some scripts.

I did the following sequence:

1. created a distribution using setup.py
2. created a virtual environment using virtualenv,
3. called "activate.bat"
4. installed my package using pip (by giving the path to the .zip file)
   Things seemed to work, except that I have no idea how to run my scripts. If I try to run example.py, I get the message (I'm using Windows):

'example.py' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

I don't see any evidence of this file residing anywhere, except in the original .zip file. So how do I run it?

[Update]
I checked, and the script files are not in the virtual environment directory anywhere.

The setup.py file looks like this:

```
from distutils.core import setup

setup(name='Fixedwidth',
      version='1.0',
      description='Parser for fixed-width records',
      author='Daryl McCullough',
      author_email='dmccullough@decisionpatterns.com',
      package_dir={'fixedwidth':'lib'},
      packages=['fixedwidth', 'fixedwidth.profiling'],
      scripts=['test/example.py', 'test/unittest.py']
      )
```

Comment: Assuming the scripts in your pacakge were in the `bin/` directory, your scripts were installed to the `bin/` directory in your virtualenv. You need the bin/ directory in your virtualenv to be a part of your PATH environment variable.

Comment: If you don't see your example.py file in the bin/ or Scripts/ directory, then you need to adjust your setup.py, see http://docs.python.org/2/distutils/setupscript.html#distutils-installing-scripts

Comment: The file example.py is nowhere in the Scripts directory (on windows, there is no bin directory). I've included the setup.py file above.)

Answer (score 0):

Okay, this was, as I suspected, something completely stupid. I was getting confused between the two different "Scripts" directories, and I was running the wrong "pip", and the result was that it was installing the package into the main python directory, not the virtual environment.